# Postgres recursive function with return - on dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create function on postgresql db using dbeaver. but when trying to save function i get error. its says "syntax error at or near "RETURN"". Maybe some one will see where is the problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.concept_children_by_id(concept_id bigint)
 RETURNS TABLE(concept_description character varying, component_id bigint, father_id bigint, curr_level integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
    BEGIN 
        WITH RECURSIVE OURCTE(component_id, father_id, curren_level) AS
        (
            SELECT 
                rel."sourceId",
                rel."destinationId",
                1::integer
            FROM 
                en."sct2_Relationship_Snapshot_INT" AS rel
            WHERE 
                rel."destinationId" = concept_id
                AND 
                rel.active = '1'  
                AND 
                rel."typeId" = 116680003
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                    e."sourceId",
                    e."destinationId",
                    rl.curren_level + '1'
                FROM
                    OURCTE rl,
                    en."sct2_Relationship_Snapshot_INT" e                       
                WHERE 
                    e."destinationId" = rl."component_id" 
                    AND 
                    e.active = '1' 
                    AND 
                    e."typeId" = 116680003
            )   
            RETURN QUERY 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    des.term, 
                    O.component_id, 
                    O.father_id, 
                    O.curren_level  
                FROM OURCTE O
                INNER JOIN en."sct2_Description_Snapshot-en_INT" des ON (O.component_id = des."conceptId")
                WHERE 
                    des."typeId" = 900000000000003001;
                ORDER BY curren_level;
            RETURN;  
    END;
 $function$
```

Comment: The `RETURN; ` makes no sense. What are you trying to do with that? You already have a `return query` immediately before that. Does it work if you remove that stray `return;`

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you just want to return the result of a query, you don't need PL/pgSQL, a simple `language sql` function will be more efficient

Comment: Finally made it. Like you said @a_horse_with_no_name `return;` made no sense. Also had to move    `RETURN QUERY ;` upwards right before  `WITH RECURSIVE OURCTE... ;`